# Wordpress 3.5.1: restrict default search widget to search on specific categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using `WP Subdomains` plugin which is working perfect and I can restrict posts to show where I want by the sub-domain slug. But if I search for word using wordpress default search widget it shows all posts regardless of the sub-domain.

I don't know how can I restrict search to filter posts and show only with respect to the sub-domain and in case of upgrade how can I stop to override my newly created search widget.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay I did it with my custom search page.

Comment: This is useless without an actual explanation, and should not be the chosen "best answer".

Answer (score 1):

Search Everything plugin is having a area where you can exclude categories you want. but I dont know what about subdomains and WP Subdomains. Please to feedback if you managed to use the two plugins at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the default search of wordpress you have to edit your the page where the searchform is sending the typed text. Searchform is just sending informations, what you have to check is the destination file.

Check this link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: I stuck at: Select the Manage Pages panel. as there is no such option name Manage Page.

Comment: If think "Manage Page" is an old feature ( v2.5 screenshots ). Anyway, the fact is you want to show your results in a page, just create a page with a new template you've created and follow the tutorial after 'Preserving Search Page Results and Pagination'

Comment: I've seen that after reading your edited post. Hope it helps.